# Click on a table link in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Please find the sample code below

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="menubox">
      <table id="menubar"  border="0">
        <tbody>
          <tr id="mytr">
            <td class="level1" id="panel" onclick="popupwin    onmouseover="this.classname onclick="popupwin"> menu1</td>
            <td class="level1" id="panel" onclick="popupwin    onmouseover="this.classname onclick="popupwin"> menu2</td>
            <td class="level1" id="panel" onclick="popupwin    onmouseover="this.classname onclick="popupwin"> menu3</td>
```

I am tring to access the menu3 column which is a link by xpath

`//table[@id='menubar']/tbody/tr/td[3]` but throwing an error no such element 
found. could any one suggest what is wrong in the xpath ?

Comment: Did you try ? `//*[@id='menubar']/tbody/tr/td[3]`

Comment: @ bhargav julaganti , Is that your table structure code is right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you please try this:-

```
//tr[@id='mytr']//td[3]
```

Comment: Can you please also explain in answer that why OP's xpath not working.So he can understand his mistake.

Comment: Now I am able to click on xpath,but once I clicked on the element there are 2 more links popped up,where I could not inspect the property of the element

Comment: wc @Bhargavjulaganti :) .... Please post the rest areas on which you got problems in a new ticket and let me know here. As Stack is not allowing to ask multiple questions on a single post. Thanks :)

Comment: thanks @ShubhamJain. I have posted the same question in other ticket could you please help me with that "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33025922/click-on-javascript-div-link-in-selenium-webdriver"

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why your Xpath wasn't working, your table structure and xpath is matching together.

However please try following xpath which might work. and if the website your testing is public. please provide the link.

```
//tr[@id='mytr']/td[contains(text(),'menu3')]
```