# click on javascript div link in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
<td class="menubox22" colspan="2">
   <table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 border=0 class="mybox1">
      <tr>
         <td id="tdMenuBar" class="mybox1">
            <table id="tblMenuBar" border="0" cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0>
               <tr id="mytr">
                  <td id="PanelTable" onmouseover="this.className='menulevel1hl';" onmouseout="this.className='menulevel1norm'" class="menulevel1norm" onclick="PopupWin('Left',divMenu1,this,'.menuitempopuprownormal','.menuitempopuprowhighlight','','.menuitempopupscroll');">
                     &nbsp;Alerts&nbsp;
                  </td>
                  <td id="PanelTable" onmouseover="this.className='menulevel1hl';" onmouseout="this.className='menulevel1norm'" class="menulevel1norm" onclick="PopupWin('Left',divMenu2,this,'.menuitempopuprownormal','.menuitempopuprowhighlight','','.menuitempopupscroll');">
                     &nbsp;Inventory&nbsp;
                  </td>
                  <td id="PanelTable" onmouseover="this.className='menulevel1hl';" onmouseout="this.className='menulevel1norm'" class="menulevel1norm" onclick="PopupWin('Left',divMenu3,this,'.menuitempopuprownormal','.menuitempopuprowhighlight','','.menuitempopupscroll');">
                     &nbsp;RTAM Exclusion&nbsp;
                  </td>
                  <td id="PanelTable" onmouseover="this.className='menulevel1hl';" onmouseout="this.className='menulevel1norm'" class="menulevel1norm" onclick="PopupWin('Left',divMenu4,this,'.menuitempopuprownormal','.menuitempopuprowhighlight','','.menuitempopupscroll');">
                     &nbsp;Sales Order&nbsp;
                  </td>
                  <div id="divMenu20110329014658433878" name="actiondiv" style="visibility:hidden;position:absolute;border:">
                     <DIV myonclick="window.parent.location.href='/smcfs/console/order.search';">
                        Sales Order Console
                     </DIV>
                     <DIV myonclick="window.parent.location.href='/smcfs/console/shipment.search';">
                        Outbound Shipment Console
                     </DIV>
                  </div>
```

I am trying to click on **Sales Order Console** which is in the table row. I tried to access with `xpath://*[@id='divMenu4']/div[1]`, which will be visible once I click on the Sales Order link, but I cannot access it.

Answer (score 0):

Given the div containing "Sales Order Console" becomes visible after you click on the "Sales Order" td element, these xpath locators should do the job.

For the "Sales Order" td element:
//td[contains(text(), 'Sales Order')]

For the "Sales Order Console" element:
//div[@name='actiondiv']/div[1]

Comment: I have tried the xpath //div[@id='divMenu20110329014658433878']/div[1] since their are multiple ones with names. could you suggest me any alternate?

Answer (score 0):

Please try below Xpath:-

```
//td[@id='PanelTable'][4]
```

OR More specific

```
//td[@id='PanelTable' and contains(text(),'Sales Order')]
```

Please get back to me if still facing any issue :)